# Constraint Error running Heapify SiftDown

Tags: ada, constraintexception

I am writing this code in Ada for a class where we have to teach ourselves the code. I understand heap sort, but the Ada syntax is really confusing me. I don't understand why I am getting a constraint error in this sort function.
Essentially we have to pass array "A" into this procedure, and it should organize it. I get the constraint error at siftDown(A(Start...A'Last));

Thank you in advance

```
Procedure sort_3(A : in out array_type) is

  procedure swap(Left : in out Integer; Right : in out Integer) is
     temp : Integer;
  begin
     temp := Left;
     Left := Right;
     Right := Temp;
  end swap;
  
  procedure siftDown(A : in out array_type) is
     Count : Integer := 1;
     root : Integer := Integer'Pos(A'First);
     child : Integer := Integer'Pos(A'Last);
     last : Integer := Integer'Pos(A'Last);
  begin
     while root * 2 + 1 <= last loop
        child := root * 2 + 1;
        if child + 1 <= last and then A(Integer'Val(child)) < A(Integer'Val(child + 1)) then
           child := child + 1;
        end if;
        if A(Integer'Val(root)) < A(Integer'Val(child)) then
           swap(A(Integer'Val(root)), A(Integer'Val(child)));
           root := child;
        else
           exit;
        end if;
     end loop;
  end siftDown;

  procedure heapify(A : in out array_type) is
     Count : Integer := 0;
     First_Pos : Integer;
     Last_Pos  : Integer;
     Start     : Integer;
  begin
     First_Pos := A'First;
     Last_Pos  := A'Last;
     Start     := Integer'Val((Last_Pos - First_Pos + 1) / 2);
      loop
       siftDown(A(Start...A'Last));
        if Start > Integer'First then
           Start := Integer'Pred(Start);
       else
           exit;
        end if;
     end loop;
  end heapify;
  Last_Index : Integer := Integer'Last;
  
   begin
  heapify(A);
  while Last_Index > Integer'First loop
     swap(A(Last_Index), A(A'First));
     Last_Index := Integer'Pred(Last_Index);
     siftDown(A(A'First..Last_Index));
  end loop;
 
end sort_3;
```

Comment: How do you define the type array_type? I am curious why you use the expression Integer'Pos in procedure siftDown during initializaton of your local variables. I am also curious why you use the expression Integer'val in your conditional expressions. Is array_type an unconstrained array type?

Comment: Our professor told us to look at heap sort in rosetta code as an example, and that's just how they did it there. It is constrained and declared in another file, the "driver" that he uses to test everyone's submittions.

Comment: That implementation is a generic heapsort using any discrete type as an array index into an unconstrained array type. If the array type is not generic, which I assume since your code does not show any generic parameters, then you do not need all the fancy conversions to and from index positions.

Comment: Your swap procedure assumes the element type is Integer. Your heapify procedure assumes the array type is unconstrained when passing an array slice to the shiftDown procedure.

Comment: Adding your declaration of array_type would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error in the code - an extra dot in `A(Start...A'Last)`.

The syntax `A(Start..A'Last)` means a slice, part of array from Start to the last element. The `Constraint_Error` means that `Start` not in array bounds. Try to add

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Start'Image);
```

before that line and you will see Start values and when it became out of the A'Range.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has some references to Integer'First and Integer'Last, which are huge values that have nothing to do with the array A and its values. I'm pretty sure you should use A'First and A'Last instead.

Also a note on style: Using the same identifier, "A", for the parameter of the local (inner, nested) procedures as for the parameter "A" of the containing (outer) procedure, when these arrays can be different, invites confusion and errors. Better to use different identifiers.